# Extension method Average() C#

Tags: c#, .net

First of all you all need to know that I don't want to use the LINQ library in C#.

Now I want to write an Extension method that returns the average of different lists. This are the lists

```
integers = new List<int> { 5, 76, 3, 93, 143, 5, 11, 67, 5 };
doubles = new List<double> { 1.23, 68.256, 44.55, 96.127, 393.4567, 2.45, 4.1 };
persons = new List<Person>
{
   new Person {Firstname = "John", Lastname = "last", Age = 66, Sallary = 1513},
   new Person {Firstname = "Donald", Lastname = "last", Age = 77, Sallary = 3100}
};
```

This is what I already got:

```
  public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        IList<int> list = source as IList<int>;
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Err");
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += list[i];
        }
        return sum / list.Count;
    }
```

I am only able to calculate the average of my integer list. I also want to calculate the average of the double list and the average salary of my persons list.

This is how I will call the function where the persons list average salary should be calculated

```
persons.Average(x => x.Sallary).ShowSingle("persons.Average(x => x.Sallary)");
```

Comment: `source as IList<int>` will return `null` if the enumerable is not actually a list. Better just iterate over the enumerable using foreach keeping track of the number of items encountered along the way. And for `IEnumerable<double>`: just add another overload of your method.

Comment: You said you dont want to use the Linq extensions but you can also take the code you need and copy these parts to your codebase. F.e. the Average calculations can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). But I am very interested why you dont want to use Linq? It is simply there and very well tested.

Comment: People question why you don't want to use LINQ because you seem like a new programmer, and many of us went through phases of demented ideas like not wanting to use libraries for fear they would bloat our programs.

Comment: i am still extremely curious _why_ you don't want to use the tried, proven and free LINQ library - because there still is no reason to reinvent the wheel - with corners.

Answer (score 2):

First, your `Average` method returns the wrong result for the integer list since you are using integer division (it returns `45` instead of `45.3333`).

To make it work with double, you need to create an overload that is using `IEnumerable<double>` etc.

```
public static double Average(this IEnumerable<double> source)
{
    IList<double> list = source as IList<double>;

    if (source == null || source.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Err");

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += list[i];
    }

    return sum / list.Count;
}
```

You can simplify the method a bit by using `foreach`:

```
public static double Average(this IEnumerable<double> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Err");

    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (double entry in source)
    {
        sum += entry;
        count+=1;
    }

    if (count == 0) return 0;

    return sum / count;
}
```

Comment: I also want to use it for my int list

Comment: do you understand what an overload is?

Comment: And your second method is not only simpler but also more general, as not all enumerables implement `IList`

Answer (score 0):

Like written in my comment you can use the implementation from the Linq repository. I have just changed the way how they process it on 0 count of items.

```
    public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        long sum = 0;
        long count = 0;
        checked
        {
            foreach (int v in source)
            {
                sum += v;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (double)sum / count;
    }

    public static double Average<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }
        if(typeof(T) != typeof(int)
            && typeof(T) != typeof(double)
            && typeof(T) != typeof(float)
            && typeof(T) != typeof(decimal)
            && typeof(T) != typeof(long))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Wrong type specified: {typeof(T)}");
        }

        double sum = 0;
        long count = 0;
        checked
        {
            foreach (T v in source)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(v);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (double)sum / count;
    }
```

A working example can be opened [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EoD9Ip)

And of course the original Linq code can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Comment: Just added both to have them as comparison. In the authors question yes you only need the one with ```double```. Like I said these are the implementations from Linq and there are all for the other types, too. But what I thinks is not the best solution is the "type-checking-while-runtime" so with a type ```<T>```.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with type checking in this case TBH, it comes along with anonymous types `<T>`. Is there a way to prove or disprove this? Of course there's the compile time/runtime, but does that mean it's bad design and or bad object oriented design?

Comment: @Codexer I have created this small example with a ```Convert.ToDouble(...)``` call. There you can see that with a generic type it always takes longer [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFcQUh). TBH without type checking and exception handling :)

Comment: Of course generic will take longer, I don't agree in that aspect. What is concerning though is, is this a bad design the OP is doing and or is this bad object oriented design from the authors? It can go both ways to be honest. Just because it takes longer doesn't warrant it can't be useful.

Comment: My first question (comment) was why not simply use Linq here because it is already contained. So if you think with OP the question I think it is a bad design to create thinks new which are already there **and** well prooven. Another point is the cast of IEnumerable to IList which is IMO a no-go. Other than that like I said I just have taken this code from the Linq git. So the authors are the devs here and I think it is maybe not the best implemention of a strict OOP point of view, but well done from a extensible point of view.

Comment: I agree, there's implementations already there to do what the OP wants to do and unfortunately the OP can't/doesn't want to use them; this could lead to unwarranted issues...

Comment: @Codexer I added now also the generic method. Not only supporting lists and more possible types (double/float/...).

Answer (score -1):

> I am only able to calculate the average of my integer list. I also want to calculate the average of the double list and the average salary of my persons list.

As already mentioned in the comments by a few user's, it would be best to extract this into separate routines. As Klaus mentioned above, `Compile-time checking is always better than run-time checking (better performance, better and earlier diagnostics)`. I agree, but as I mentioned on another answer, does this mean it's bad design from the programmer and or bad object oriented design on the authors?

Here's a little sample using generics (`<T>`), one routine does the `int` and `double` list and the other (for `Person`) is extracted out to it's own routine. The first `Average` routine uses the help of [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-5.0) to return specified type whose value is equivalent to a specified object.

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T Average<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            double dblSum = 0;
            int intSum = 0;

            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Err");
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int) && source is List<int> intList && intList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
                {
                    intSum += intList[i];
                }
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType((intSum / intList.Count), typeof(T));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(double) && source is List<double> dblList && dblList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dblList.Count; i++)
                {
                    dblSum += dblList[i];
                }
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType((dblSum / dblList.Count), typeof(T));
            }
            else
            {
                return default;
            }
        }

        public static int Average(this IEnumerable<Person> people)
        {
            int intSum = 0;
            if (people != null && people is List<Person> perList && perList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < perList.Count; i++)
                {
                    intSum += perList[i].Sallary;
                }
                return intSum / perList.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                return default;
                // throw new ArgumentNullException("Err");
            }

        }
    }
```

Please note: I am not sure the type of `Sallary` as this wasn't provided in your post. You may need to change the `Average` routine (Person) slightly to adjust to your `Sallary` type.

Answer (score -2):

We can leverage on generic types in c# to find the average. This allows us to use only one method to calculate for both integers and double.

```
 public static double Average<T>(this List<T> source)
    {
        IList<T> list = source as IList<T>;
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Err");
        if(source.GetType() == typeof(List<int>) || source.GetType() == typeof(List<double>))
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble((object)list[i]);
            }
            return sum / list.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not possible to find average");
        }
    }
```

And to call the method

```
var integers = new List<int> { 5, 76, 3, 93, 143, 5, 11, 67, 5 };
        var doubles = new List<double> { 1.23, 68.256, 44.55, 96.127, 393.4567, 2.45, 4.1 };
        Console.WriteLine(doubles.Average());
        Console.WriteLine(integers.Average());
```

Comment: Compile-time checking is always better than runtime checking (better performance, better and earlier diagnostics). So I would really prefer having separate overloads for int and double instead.

Comment: This works only for my double list and my int list. I also want it working for my persons list

Comment: @titani12 this is because Xelect(x => x.Salary)  returns an IEnumerable which is not an IList. See Adrians second method and my comments.

Comment: To use on your persons list, you can extract the salaries from the list and then call the method on the list of salaries or create an overloaded approach that works specifically for the list of Persons

Comment: @KlausGütter , The method of overloading was already provided in another comment, hence the reason why I provided another alternative approach